# Been camping Vs. Gone camping

Tags: present-perfect, been-vs-gone

I already know how **been** and **gone** can be used with present perfect simple and what difference they make, but with a certain verb phrase like **go camping** would it be grammatically correct to say ***I've never gone camping*** when we are talking about not having experienced a specific activity up to the present moment in life or it should be ***I've never been camping***?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I would say both are equally correct.

When you say, "Where was Fred last week?" the reply would be "He's been camping" (and he's back now).

When you say, "Where's Fred today?" the reply would be "He's gone camping" (and he won't be back till next week).

But when you say "I've never been camping" *or* "I've never gone camping", you are saying the same thing. I've never gone away and slept in a tent and come back, and also: I've never gone away and slept in a tent (whether I've come back or not).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You've chosen the verb "gone" in your final examples, but I guess in one of them "gone" should be replaced with "been". Am I right?

Comment: no, it is what it is